# Sitecore 8.0 Update 1 WFFM Submit Issue

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

I am getting the following log warning when submit a WFFM form:

```
    8380 2016:05:12 04:25:05 WARN Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: owner
    Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
    Message: Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: owner
    Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Warn(String message, Object owner)
   at Sitecore.WFFM.Core.Extensions.Warn.IsNull(Object obj, String name)
   at Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.AnalyticsTracker.get_SessionId()
   at Sitecore.Form.Core.FormDataHandler.ExecuteSaveActions(ID formId, ControlResult[] fields, ActionDefinition[] actions)
   at Sitecore.Form.Core.FormDataHandler.ProcessData(ID formID, ControlResult[] fields, ActionDefinition[] actions, CallContext context)
```

The from give me both the error message and success message (configured in the form) The form also has no save actions?

UPDATE:

This is another warning happen on the submit:

```
WARN Web Forms for Marketers: an exception 'We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request. Your data may not have been correctly saved.' has occured while trying to execute an action '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}'.
```

Comment: On submit, do you have custom code or any kind of logging?

Comment: Do you have save actions relating to xDB such as Update Contact Details?

Comment: I don't have any action on the submit.

Comment: @MohammedSyam Have u tried to fill the datasource attribute in webform  control?

Comment: Yes already filled